# SQL query to Identify number position within a range table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Hi everybody i have to make a query to determine the range that a number belongs to in a sql table, what i'm doing is using a between but when you use a value that applies to the last range where the final value is null it does not bring results, i found a workaround but i think that this is not the best way to do it. Below is an example of what i'm trying to do.

```
-- Creando temporal 
CREATE TABLE #TMP
(
    RangeID         INT 
    ,InitialValue   INT NULL
    ,FinalValue     INT NULL
)


-- Insertar valores
INSERT INTO #TMP
    (   RangeID, InitialValue, FinalValue   )
VALUES
    (   1, 100, 200 )
    ,(  2, 201, 300 )
    ,(  3, 301, NULL )


-- Verificando temporal
SELECT * FROM #TMP 

-- Verificando los rangos
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    #TMP
WHERE
    301 between     InitialValue 
    AND FinalValue

--RETURNS NOTHING

SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    #TMP
WHERE
    301 between     InitialValue 
    AND isnull(FinalValue,301+1) 


--RETURNS THE DESIRED RESULT 

-- Borrando temporal
DROP TABLE #TMP
```

The problem is that when the final value is null i have to use the isnull to validate and assign a value to it.

Is there any other way to  approach to this problem.

Comment: Please tag your question with the specific DBMS you're using.

Comment: I'm using sql server 2008 r2

Comment: What result do you want if the input value is 400?

Comment: the result should be that the value belongs to the range number 3 because i want to use the null in that range to represent any value greater than 301

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of options:

```
WHERE 301 between InitialValue AND isnull(FinalValue,9999) 
--Some value high enough to encompass all possible values

WHERE 301 >= Initial Value AND (301 <= FinalValue OR FinalValue IS NULL)
--Instead of between, use >= AND <=, and make exception for null upper limit
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on having `NULL` as the final value, then no, there's no other way than checking for nulls, in general.

But you could do

```
INSERT INTO #TMP
    (   RangeID, InitialValue, FinalValue   )
VALUES
    (   1, 100, 200 )
    ,(  2, 201, 300 )
    ,(  3, 301, 2147483647 )
```

2147483647 being the maximum integer possible.

***EDIT**: I just noticed, however, that i.e. 302 would fail **your** test.*